# Embed plotly fig.to_html into Vue component

Tags: vue.js, plotly, vue-component

I have generated a plotly graph called fig and it is saved as a fig.to_html in a django model, which I am exporting to Vue using graphql.

Vue receives the data no problem though when displaying the element I am getting the HTML code and not the graph image.

What is the correct way to display the chart and not the HTML code?

These are my settings for saving the chart to HTML:

```
        config = dict({
            'displayModeBar': True,
            'displaylogo': False,
            'modeBarButtonsToRemove': [
                'toImage',
                'select2d',
                'lasso2d',
            ],

        })
    
        fig.to_html(config=config, include_plotlyjs=False, full_html=False)
```

Here is my Vue component. signal.signalChart is the plotly HTML element:

```
<template>
  <div class="signal" v-if="signal">
    <h2>{{ signal.symbol }}: {{ signal.marketOpen }}</h2>
    <div>{{ displayableDate(signal.date) }}</div>
    <ul>
      <li>{{ signal.bias }}</li>
      <li>{{ signal.tradeType }}</li>
    </ul>
    <p v-html="signal.signalChart">{{ signal.signalChart }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export default {
  name: "Signal",
  data() {
    return {
      signal: null,
    };
  },
  async created() {
    const signal = await this.$apollo.query({
      query: gql`
        query ($slug: String!) {
          signalBySlug(slug: $slug) {
            symbol
            marketOpen
            date
            bias
            tradeType
            signalChart
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        slug: this.$route.params.slug,
      },
    });
    this.signal = signal.data.signalBySlug;
  },
  methods: {
    displayableDate(date) {
      return new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { dateStyle: "full" }).format(
        new Date(date)
      );
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was presented [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/qg8xlp/embed_plotlyioto_html_string_containing/hiaio7y/?context=3)

The latter part of their solution was indeed the answer and something I had not considered.

You can theoretically use a watcher, ref, the DOM api, and eval() to do what you want. A better way, though, would be to get the chart's data, not its html, and build the chart safely using vue components.

```
<template>
  <div class="signal" v-if="signal">
    <h2>{{ signal.symbol }}: {{ signal.marketOpen }}</h2>
    <div>{{ displayableDate(signal.date) }}</div>
    <ul>
      <li>{{ signal.bias }}</li>
      <li>{{ signal.tradeType }}</li>
    </ul>
    <p ref="chart" v-html="signal.signalChart"></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
  name: "Signal",
  data() {
    return {
      signal: null,
    };
  },
  async created() {
    const signal = await this.$apollo.query({
      query: gql`
        query ($slug: String!) {
          signalBySlug(slug: $slug) {
            symbol
            marketOpen
            date
            bias
            tradeType
            signalChart
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        slug: this.$route.params.slug,
      },
    });
    this.signal = signal.data.signalBySlug;
  },
  methods: {
    displayableDate(date) {
      return new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { dateStyle: "full" }).format(
        new Date(date)
      );
    },
  },

  watch: {
    'signal.signalChart': {
      async handler() {
        if (this.$refs.chart) {
          await Vue.nextTick();

          [...this.$refs.chart.querySelectorAll('script')].forEach((scriptElement) => {
            if (scriptElement.textContent) {
              eval(scriptElement.textContent);
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```